# Object Reference Not Set To An Instance Of An Object: Yelp Return Values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, yelp

I'm making a call to Yelp, to get reviews for some addresses in an apartment finder I've written, but it looks like some of the Yelp data isn't complete, so the following code results in Ye Olde ORNSTAIOAN error:

```
    public IEnumerable<Review> GetReviews(Bounds searchBounds) {
        var yelp = new Y.Yelp(ConfigOptions);
        var searchOptions = GetSearchOptions(searchBounds);
        var searchTask = yelp.Search(searchOptions);
        var tasks = new Task<Y.Data.SearchResults>[GetTaskArraySize(searchTask)];

        tasks[0] = searchTask;

        for (var i = 1; i < tasks.Length; i++) {
            searchOptions.GeneralOptions.offset = i * YelpResultsLimit;
            tasks[i] = yelp.Search(searchOptions);
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);

        return tasks.SelectMany(t => t.Result.businesses != null
            ? t.Result.businesses
            : null)
                    .Select(MapYelpBusinessToReview);
    }
```

The error hits in the return line, on "businesses", even if I try a null catch, as I am above. The error outputs as:

```
<Error>
    <script id="tinyhippos-injected"/>
    <Message>
        An error has occurred.
    </Message>
    <ExceptionMessage>
        Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    </ExceptionMessage>
    <ExceptionType>
        System.NullReferenceException
    </ExceptionType>
    <StackTrace>
        at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at ApartmentFinder.Infrastructure.Services.SearchEngine.<>c__DisplayClassc.<FindProperties>b__1() in c:\Development\myProject\ApartmentFinder.Infrastructure\Services\SearchEngine.cs:line 25 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
    </StackTrace>
</Error>
```

How can I trap the missing business information, and proceed with/without it?

Update:

[image: YelpSharp.Data.Business]

```
namespace ApartmentFinder.Infrastructure.Models {
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides the set of properties describing a review for a property.
    /// </summary>
    public class Review {
        public string Id{ get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string Address{ get; set; }
        public string City{ get; set; }
        public string State{ get; set; }
        public string ZipCode{ get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber{ get; set; }
        public string RatingImageUrl{ get; set; }
        public int NumberOfReviews{ get; set; }
        public string Snippet{ get; set; }
        public string Url{ get; set; }
        public double Latitude{ get; set; }
        public double Longitude{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Adding in the method for Review MapYelpBusinessToReview:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Maps a <see cref="Y.Data.Business"/> instance to a new <see cref="Review"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="business">Business object to map.</param>
    /// <returns>A new <see cref="Review"/> instance.</returns>
    static Review MapYelpBusinessToReview(Y.Data.Business business) {
        return new Review {
            Id = business.id,
            Name = business.name,
            Address = business.location.address[0],
            City = business.location.city,
            State = business.location.state_code,
            ZipCode = business.location.postal_code,
            PhoneNumber = business.phone,
            RatingImageUrl = business.rating_img_url,
            Snippet = business.snippet_text,
            Url = business.url,
            NumberOfReviews = business.review_count,

        };
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the `SelectMany` call you end up returning a `null` value instead of an empty collection to.  In the case you want no values added you must return an empty collection else `SelectMany` will null ref

Try the following

```
return tasks
  .SelectMany(t => t.Result.businesses ?? new List<Business>())
  .Select(MapYelpBusinessToReview);
```

Comment: I see where you're going on this, but the issue I run into with that is:

`Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<YelpSharp.Data.Business>' and 'ApartmentFinder.Infrastructure.Models.Review[]'` (Adding view of YelpSharp.Data.Business, and Review above)

Comment: @PKD fixed that error.  Just needed to change the type to `List<Review>` to match the left hand side

Comment: Heh! Quick on the draw.

Comment: `Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<YelpSharp.Data.Business>' and 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ApartmentFinder.Infrastructure.Models.Review>'`

Comment: @PKD ah, missed that the mapping occured on the following `Select`

Comment: Any other ideas on this? I feel like it's really close! :)

Comment: Heya, @JaredPar - Any more thoughts on this?

Comment: @PKD what's the problem at this point?  It looks like it should work here

Comment: @PKD the current code should fix that.  The types on both the left and right of `??` are `List<Business>` now.

Comment: @PKD it was 4 days ago but now both sides should be of the same type.  If they aren't you simply need to make the `new List<XXX>` call have the correct type in there.  Based on the error message it needs to be either Business or Review.  I've posted both as answers and you seem to be rejecting both of them.  Something is amiss here because they are the only 2 correct ansewrs based on the error messages you are posting

Comment: I'm not rejecting anything, but when I've tried your solutions, they've resulted in more errors. I've tried working through them, but the result has been even more errors. :) So, your current solution is: `return tasks
  .SelectMany(t => t.Result.businesses ?? new List<Business>())
  .Select(MapYelpBusinessToReview);`. I'll try it again today, and see where I get to with it.

Comment: @PKD but what are the new errors?  So far you've only posted the one which I've seemingly solved.

Comment: Ok - using `return tasks.SelectMany(t => t.Result.businesses ?? new List<Business>()).Select(MapYelpBusinessToReview);`, and it works! You rock, man. It had an error at first, but I resolved that with a reference, and blammo, all's well!

Comment: The reference to resolve the final error was to add 
`using YelpSharp.Data;` and `using YelpSharp.Data.Options;` in my usings.

Comment: Now, @JaredPar, if you were also a god of KendoUI, and MVC Razor... I'd have another one in another project to ask you about. :)