# Catch block never firing inside a LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have some data I am deserializing inside a `Linq` statement:

```
var scheduledData = results
   .Where(o => o.Result.IsValid)
   .SelectMany(o => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CalendarJob>>(o.Result.Response))
   .ToList();
```

This is throwing an error. I never see this error in the debugger. The returned web page lists a 500 error showing this. So I added some handing:

```
var scheduledData = results
   .Where(o => o.Result.IsValid)
   .SelectMany(o => {
      try {
         return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CalendarJob>>(o.Result.Response);
      }
      catch {
         return new List<CalendarJob>();
      }
   })
   .ToList();
```

Yes this is really ugly. I **only** did this so I could put a breakpoint on the `catch` block so I could inspect some values. This is not code I would leave in place! :)

I put a breakpoint on the `return` statement inside the `try` block and also the `catch` block. Then I execute the code. The `try` statement hits and execution is gone. The `catch` block never fires nor does any other code in my method.

Should this `catch` block be allowed in `linq`? I sure thought so?

Yes, I am in debug mode. Yes, I have cleaned and rebuilt. The breakpoint on my try block does indeed hit. I can inspect the value of the string about to be deserialized and the value is not right. It's `""`. I do not mean `string.Empty`, I specifically mean the string contains two bytes and both are the double quote character. The service I am getting the data from is not returning good data. But my `catch` block never fires.

One more thing to note. I put the entire thing into a `try...catch` block and that catch block *does* hit. Only the one inside `LINQ` does not.

Comment: You can definitely put a breakpoint inside a catch in the way you have. I suspect your issue is that the catch is never being entered because the exception is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Can you try using foreach loop to find the error and then switch back to linq after fixing? Would be time saving...

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this problem with: `Enumerable.Range(0,20).Select(i => {
  try{
   return i/(i%2 - 1);
  }catch{
   Console.WriteLine("catch");
   return i;
  }
 }).ToList();`. It writes the string "catch" 10 times.

Comment: Are you compiled in debug mode without compiler optimizations?

Comment: Maybe o.Result is null and exception was really thrown in Where expression

Comment: The breakpoint in my `try` block hits. I can see the problem directly. The string being deserialized is not valid. I press F10 to step over it and get a 500 error. I have cleaned and rebuilt the application. I am in debug mode.

Comment: What is the exception you get in your outer `try ... catch` block?  That should tell you what's failing.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the `ToList()` or the`Were()` thats throwing the exception? If your where returns nothing you'll get a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: @Liam - As stated I can watch the error happen. It's not the `where`. I assure you. The specific error is *Object reference not set to an instance of an object* and it happens in the `SelectMany.MoveNext()` area. I can see this from when I added the outer `try...catch`.

Comment: Looks like a duplciate of [this then](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22152839/542251) *The problem is that in the SelectMany call you end up returning a null value instead of an empty collection*

Comment: Yes, that's what I figured out eventually and wrote below. Thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - this will work the way you think it will.

The only time it won't work will be an exception you cannot catch, like a `StackOverflowException`.

To prove it, just execute the folllowing code in Visual Studio, or Linqpad and observe the breakpoint is hit twice.

```
var list = new List<string>
{
    "a",
    "b"
};

list.Select(i =>
{
    try
    {
        return int.Parse(i);
    }
    catch
    {
        return 0; // Put a breakpoint here.
    }
}).ToList();
```

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer because I can test your code and new code I have written where the catch block does fire. This means I am doing something wrong in my code. I do not know what, but my question of `catch` being used inside `Linq` is answered.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause. Internally `JsonConvert` doesn't throw an error with invalid Json. Instead it returns null. So my `try...catch` block around the `JsonConvert` didn't do anything because there was nothing to catch. Next, `SelectMany` was expecting a `List<>` item back and tried to enumerate it to select the elements out of it. Because it received `null`, the error was thrown here and not inside the Json conversion. This is why the outer `try...catch` picks up the error but the one in the OP above does not.

I accepted RB's answer because he answers my original question. This is simply an explanation for any future finders.